# Using angular-ui-routing, why is my express routing not working?

Tags: angularjs, express, angular-ui-router

I am using angular-ui/ui-routing. The problem lies with either my angular routing, or my server routing, I don't know which. My express routing is this:

```
var compositions = require('../controllers/comptroller');    
module.exports = function(Compositions, app, auth) {

        app.route('/critique')
        .post(auth.requiresLogin, compositions.createCritique);

    app.route('/users')
    .get(compositions.showProfile);

    app.route('/compositions/:compositionId')
    .get(compositions.show)
    .post(auth.requiresLogin, compositions.createCritique);

    app.route('/compositions')
   // .get(compositions.profile)
    .get(compositions.all)
    .post(auth.requiresLogin, compositions.fileUpload);
```

and my angular routing is this:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('all compositions', {
    url: '/compositions/recent',
    templateUrl: 'compositions/views/list.html'
  }).
state('create comp', {
    url: '/compositions/create',
    templateUrl: 'compositions/views/create.html',
     resolve: {
            loggedin: checkLoggedin
        }
}).
state('myuser', {
    url: '/users',
    templateUrl: 'compositions/views/profile.html',
     resolve: {
            loggedin: checkLoggedin
        }
}).
```

I am using a state machine to handle routing. When I navigate to localhost:3000/#!/users I receive my profile.html template, which is what I want. However, the GET request on my express route never gets called. I am trying to get the function 'showProfile' but it never hits the function. UNLESS, I navgiate to localhost:3000/users, then the function, showProfile gets called, but the template, profile.html does not. Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong? I need to get to the showProfile function in order to query my mongo database. Any advice or help is appreciated, thank you.

EDIT: Interesting to note, if I were to put compositions.showProfile in another app.route, I hit the backend function, and load the template. It's for this route, /users, it does not seem to work.

Comment: When you hit `localhost:3000/#!/users`, the browser goes to `localhost:3000` and asks for `/`. The hash value (`#!/users`) is never sent the web server. That is used by the client side router to decide what template to load.

Comment: @AnthonyChu but I do get different results when I go to localhost:3000/users compared to localhost:3000/#!/users

Comment: That's expected. A way to think about it is the part before the `#` is sent to the server, the `#` and anything after it is not. In the case of `localhost:3000/users`, the browser is requesting the `/user` resource from the server, and that matches the `/users` route in express.

Comment: @AnthonyChu so, do  you know how I would fix it so that it does not request resources according to whether or not the # is there or not?

Comment: What does `/users` do? Typically you'd let client side routing load the template and then issue REST calls to the server to retrieve data to render in the template.

Comment: @AnthonyChu /users is supposed to be the logged in user's profile.

Comment: Then what is `compositions/views/profile.html`? I would think you'd either bypass angular altogether and serve the entire page from the server (`/user`) or keep the routing on the client side to load the template but call a REST endpoint on the server to retrieve the current user's profile to render.

Comment: @AnthonyChu I'd like to get information about the user when you navigate to /users, but my backend methods are never called. The templateUrl is simply the template of the html page. The express routing is supposed to be called and get information about the user and return it so it can be formatted.

Comment: @AnthonyChu I don't see a email attached to your account when I visit your profile page

Comment: Sorry guess email's not there directly, but can be found on my site. Anyway, still not totally clear what `/users` is. Does it return json or HTML or something else? If you keep using client side routing, `/users` should return json, and add a controller to your route (state) and make an ajax call to `/users` from the controller and use the data to populate your template.